# importxml in googlesheets from formatted XML (not html)

Tags: xml, xpath, google-sheets-formula

i'm trying to obtain a USD/EUR rate from the ECB site. it comes in XML, however when i use what i assume should be the xpath it yields an empty result and #N/A in googlesheets. obviously i'm defining the xpath wrong but i've tried several things and it's always empty:

here's the actual data api URL:

https://sdw-wsrest.ecb.europa.eu/service/data/EXR/D.USD.EUR.SP00.A?startPeriod=2020-06-30&endPeriod=2020-06-30

when inputting this + xpath into importxml() i tried this:

=IMPORTXML("https://sdw-wsrest.ecb.europa.eu/service/data/EXR/D.USD.EUR.SP00.A?startPeriod=2020-06-30&endPeriod=2020-06-30", "/generic:Obs/generic:ObsValue[1]")

no go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `IMPORTDATA`, `QUERY` and `REGEXEXTRACT` for this case :

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY(IMPORTDATA(B4);"select * WHERE Col1 starts with '<generic:ObsValue'");"=.(\d.\d+)")
```

Output :

[image: USDEU]

Comment: done. yup worked like a charm and i learned a few things in the process, many thanks!